# Permission denied each time I open a new terminal window

Tags: bash

Every time I open a new terminal session I received the following error. Not sure how to fix this, do I need to edit .bash_profile. Below is error and contents:

```
Last login: Mon Mar  5 13:10:22 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/myname/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

Contents of bash file:

```
~/.bash_profile
alias flush='sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder'
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: You have to source `~/.bash_profile` with `source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile`. It's not meant for standalone execution. If "bash file" *is* `~/.bash_profile` then you need to remove this line all together

Comment: Don't source `.bash_profile` *from* `.bash_profile`; that creates a infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks. So changing ~/.bash_profile to source ~/.bash_profile or .~/.bash_profile will fix the problem? Sorry, total newbie.

Comment: You guys rock, I removed the ~/.bash_profile line. Thank you!